# files are being downloaded with .html suffix

Tags: safari, html

Every time I download a file from my school site, it gets `.html` suffix.
For example, if I download a file called file.docx from my school site through the safari, it is saved in my downloads directory as `file.docx.html`.

This issue happens *just* at my school website and *not* at any other website whatsoever. Additionally it happens just through Safari and not through Chrome or any other browser.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you the only one to have this trouble or everyone else at your school using safari has it too?

Comment: safari and chrome run on various versions of iOS, Windows, OS X - please edit the post to specify a specific piece of apple hardware and software that's in play and consider listing the school website in case someone knows that this is a "feature" of drupal or another publication platform that's being used. Also, it would be good to know if you can edit the extension and the documents work and it's a naming issue or if the document itself is unworkable when downloaded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363744/safari-adding-html-to-download

Answer (score 1):

This is outside of your control - the headers being sent by the school's web server determine what file type Safari thinks it is, and therefore appends the extension it thinks is appropriate. In this case, most likely the `Content-Type` and/or `Content-Disposition` headers are not being sent, or not being sent correctly. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487365/http-header-for-downloading-microsoft-word-and-excel-files) for a more technical explanation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363744/safari-adding-html-to-download